# Changing the currentIndex() of a tab widget when a different item is selected from a drop-down box

Tags: c++, python, qt, porting

I'm new to *C++*  and I'm just start to port a program that was originally in **python/Qt** to **C++/Qt** in order to take advantage of a better terminal widget that I can embed in my program. Right now I'm a bit stuck, I'm trying to setup where if a different item from a drop-down box is selected the `currentIndex()` of a tab widget is changed accordingly.

Heres my code so far:

```
    //main.cpp

    #include <QApplication>
    #include "mainwindow.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

heres the mainwindow.h

```
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    #define MAINWINDOW_H

    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include <QTimer>


    namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
    }

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();
        QTimer *timer;
        void startMyTimer()
        {
            timer = new QTimer();
            timer->setInterval(1);
            timer->start();
            QObject::connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(changeIndex()));
        }

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        void changeIndex();
         };

    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And lastly heres the mainwindow.cpp

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        changeIndex();
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

    void MainWindow::changeIndex()
    {
        if (ui->comboBox->currentText() == "add-apt-repository")
        {
            ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
            ui->checkBox->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
        }
        if (ui->comboBox->currentText() == "apt-get")
        {
            ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
            ui->checkBox->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
        }
        if (ui->comboBox->currentText() == "aptitude")
        {
           ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(2);
           ui->checkBox->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
        }
        if (ui->comboBox->currentText() == "bzr")
        {
            ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(3);
            ui->checkBox->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        }
        if (ui->comboBox->currentText() == "cd")
        {
            ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(4);
            ui->checkBox->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        }
        if (ui->comboBox->currentText() == "chmod")
        {
            ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(5);
            ui->checkBox->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
        }
    }
```

I've looked at a bunch of QTimer examples but I'm at a loss.
I also tried doing `if (ui->comboBox->changeEvent())` but I was probably using that wrong as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you probably have to mark `changeIndex()` as a slot, like this:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // ...

    private slots: 
        void changeIndex();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
}
```

This also requires you to invoke the Qt meta object compiler. If you use qmake, that's already done for you. Otherwise, it depends on your build system.

Second, is there any particular reason for using the timer? You can also connect to one of the combo box's `currentIndexChanged` signals.

Comment: No, there was no real use of the timer, I was just trying things to be honest. I'm not much of a programmer to begin with, nevermind c++. In python the way I set it up I didn't have to worry about events and signals so I'm just having trouble with this one part so far.

Comment: Thank you very very much though, this is in fact what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the timer, it's of no use here.
Instead, make changeIndex() a slot by putting it into a "private slots:" section:

```
public slots:
    void changeIndex();
```

Then connect the combobox's [currentIndexChanged signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) to your slot, in the MainWindow constructor:

```
connect( ui->combobox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(changeIndex()) );
```